# critical section in nodejs - writing data from frontend to json file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have following question that have I to synchronize requests when writing data to a file from multiple users in the same time. In java there is a synchronized keyword but I don't understand how it looks in nodejs.

```
app.post("/register",function(req,res){

      fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      var users=JSON.parse(data);
      users["users"].push(req.body);
      var check=false;
      fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", JSON.stringify(users),'utf8', function (err) {
         if(err){
            res.send(JSON.stringify("error"));
            check=true;
         }
      })
      if(!check){
         res.send(JSON.stringify("Created")); 
      }
           
   })
})
```

Comment: why json, as opposed to even just a sqlite3 file db?

Comment: there are `fs.readFileSync` and `fs.writeFileSync` but you really should use the async versions

Comment: thanks for advice for future. I wrote the code based on the json files and It would be great if I will not have to rewritten all the code.Do you think it would work on file?

Comment: simply move `if(!check){` into the writeFile callback, though your going to see a corrupt users.json file when multiple users hit that endpoint at the exact same time fs.writeFile doesn't handle a mutex lock for you

Comment: should I use readFileSync too as writeFileSync. And there is one more issue. In register I am overwriting all file and I have login route that reads user from the file. Can it be inconsistency issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use writeFileSync instead of writeFile.

It returns nothing, so if the process went to the next line, this mean the file was written successfully!!

Comment: Don't understand why Sync